# Cannot connect to database with credentials provided in db.php

Tags: config, database

I'm trying to push a site live today and am running into a problem I'm having trouble solving. I have a staging site which is a subdomain on the live server and everything works fine there but when I try to load the live site I get the following error (strange characters and all):

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Craft can't connect to the database with the credentials in craft/config/db.php.") in "_includes/_main_nav" at line 19.

The only difference between the two config files is the database name in db.php and the siteUrl and fileSystemPath in general.php. I do have a multi-environment config based on the one at straughtupcraft.com but I don't see any other difference between my live and staging environments other then what is already noted above.

Anyone run across this problem yet? Solutions?

**UPDATE:**

**index.php:**

```
<?php

//die('hey');


// Path to your craft/ folder
$craftPath = '../craft';

// Do not edit below this line
$path = rtrim($craftPath, '/').'/app/index.php';

if (!is_file($path))
{
    exit('Could not find your craft/ folder. Please ensure that <strong><code>$craftPath</code></strong> is set correctly in '.__FILE__);
}

require_once $path;


// Check the SERVER_NAME variable ourselves
switch ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) 
{
    // If the SERVER_NAME variable matches our case, 
    // assign the CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT variable a keyword 
    // that identifies this environment that we can 
    // use in our multi-environment config

    case 'site.com' :
        define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', 'live');
        break;

    case 'staging.site.com' :
        define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', 'staging');
        break;

    default :
        define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', 'dev');
        break;
}
```

**general.php**

```
return array(
    '*' => array(
        'cpTrigger' => 'site_admin',
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
        'slugWordSeparator' => "_",
    ),
    'live' => array(
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'siteUrl' => 'http://site.com',
            'fileSystemPath' => '/path/to/domains/site.com/html'
        )
    ),
    'staging' => array(
        'devMode' => true,
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'siteUrl' => 'http://staging.site.com',
            'fileSystemPath' => '/path/to/domains/staging.site.com/html'
        )
    ),
    'dev' => array(
        'devMode' => true,
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'siteUrl' => 'http://site.dev',
            'fileSystemPath' => '/users/stubear/sites/site/dev/html'
        )
    ),
);
```

**db.php**

```
return array(
    '*' => array(
        'tablePrefix' => 'craft',
    ),
    'live' => array(
        'server' => 'server',
        'user' => 'username',
        'password' => '********',
        'database' => 'craft_live_db',
    ),
    'staging' => array(
        'server' => 'server',
        'user' => 'username',
        'password' => '********',
        'database' => 'craft_staging_db',
    ),
    'dev' => array(
        'server' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
        'database' => 'site-dev',
    ),
);
```

Comment: Can you post your db and config file (with masked passwords)?

Comment: Updated question to add requested files. I've removed all the secure information from them and scrubbed the domain name as well.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the config. Can you check the db-connection and also add an echo to the switch, to be sure the server-name gets matched correctly?

Comment: Can you enable devMode, then reproduce the error then check your craft/storage/runtime/logs files for an underlying error?

Comment: Brad, it appears to be throwing a 404 error per this line in the log file (path edited):

2014/06/16 16:48:28 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.404] exception 'Craft\HttpException' in /path/to/domains/site.com/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php:751

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Move the check the SERVER_NAME `switch` up above the `require_once $path;`. You need to set `CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT` earlier.

Comment: That did it. Why would the staging and dev sites work though and not the live site?

Comment: If you had `staging` as part of the staging url, it would match (same with dev). I'm guessing there is no `live` in the live site url.

Comment: Not sure why I placed that code at the bottom of the index page on this site because two other sites I'm working on currently have it where it should go, above the //do not edit below this line comment, but there you have it. Problem solved. Craft SE to the rescue.